# apache2 - copy php scripts and "virtualize" filesystem

Tags: php, apache, apache2, virtual, jail

I have a very big code base which i need to duplicate for law reasons.

the "source website":
domain: example.com
documentroot /home/mywebs/web1

i need to clone it  to:
domain: copy.example.com
document root: different from /home/mywebs/web1

example.com uses many php skripts, which are using "raw access" to file system - like:

$fp = fopen("/home/mywebs/web1/tmp/users.dat","r");

it makes hard to truely duplicate it.

My idea is to create a "container" in the directory

/container and let it be a virtual root "/"

within this root i create

/home/mywebs/web1 and copy all the data from example.com
but the php-scripts file access to "/home/mywebs/web1" need to go to "/container/home/mywebs/web1"

anyidea how to do this?

Comment: man chroot. It's exactly what you need (other than not using hard-coded strings like that).

Comment: ok - but it should not have any side effect - i cannot chroot the entire apache, i need to create a second process and chroot it or what to do excactly?

Comment: There are a few options, but you could replace "/home/mywebs/web1" with "/" and chroot from within your application's main process(es). Then a global search and replace of "/home/mywebs/web1/" with "/" should fix everything. Apache wouldn't be within the chrooted application.

Comment: Alternatively, globally search and replace "/home/mywebs/web1/" with "$approot/" or whatever the php equivalent is... then you wouldn't even need to chroot.

Comment: hello - i did it all with a combination of find, grep and sed - thank you!

Comment: Well done. I think that makes this a not-a-programming-related question, though!